# OAuth, Tumblr and Scope

Tags: ios, oauth, scope, tumblr

I'm trying to login to Tumblr via OAuth and a Mac App I begin to code.
I donwloaded gtm-oauth source code, everything is fine.

I just began with this code inside a view controller :

```
- (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)myCustomAuth {

    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth;
    auth = [[[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                                                        consumerKey:kConsumerKey
                                                         privateKey:kConsumerSecret] autorelease];
    auth.serviceProvider = @"Custom Auth Service";
    return auth;
}
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"finishedWithAuth");
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"failed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"done");
    }
}


- (void)signInToCustomService {

    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self myCustomAuth];
    if (auth == nil) {
        NSLog(@"A valid consumer key and consumer secret are required for signing in to Tumblr");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Ok auth");
    }

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token"];
    NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token"];
    NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize"];

    NSString *scope = @"http://api.tumblr.com"; // HERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO WRITE

    GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [[[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                                language:nil
                                                         requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                       authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                          accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                          authentication:auth
                                                          appServiceName:@"My App: Custom Service"
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self signInToCustomService];
}
```

But nothing happens.

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error;
```

This method is never called.
Perhaps this is my scope variable. I don't know which value I have to write for it.
Thanks for your help !